# I wanna send string that is from s3 object to a client

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have a problem to send string that is from s3 object body to a client

I'm using aws sdk for node, and apollo server(express), express, react

I did get object from s3 and create readable stream. and then i listen data event so I might send string to a client

```
let data = '';
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
});

return { data }
```

I thought data is not a empty string but it is empty string
what can I do to solve the problem?

Edit:

```
let data = '';
function promiseBasedRequest (params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
} 

await promiseBasedRequest(params);
```

This works as I intended.

Comment: Probably you return `data` before the callback gets triggered. There are different ways to `solve` this, depending on what else you have or what exactly you want to do. `data += chunk;` would be to correct part to react to the response.

Comment: @Lain this file is html file so maybe I can render this html file to a react client. And future, I wanna render images from s3

Comment: @Bob I'm a newbie to programming, so I don't have enough knowledge of programming part. Sorry for my explanation

Comment: I'm building a web site that can post article with rich react editor(draft.js) and when user posts article, article will be converted to javascript string that has html syntax('<p> testing... <p>') and be uploaded to s3 bucket. and I wanna get object from s3 and render it to a client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the writing to `end`. First the function need to be asynchronous a promise or callback.

```
function getData(params) {
    let data = ''
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let data = '';
        s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
        .on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            res(data);
        })
        .on('error', function(){
            rej()
        })
    })
}
```

You can use the function by:

```
(async(){
    const data = await getData()
})();
```

Or `getData().then(..)`

**EDIT:** Also, `getObject` has one `promise` method as well.

```
s3.getObject(params).promise().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: I read aws-sdk developer guide before 1 min ago, and I learned that all aws requests are asynchronous. I wonder that even if I use this function, is it guarantee that await s3.getObject(this is aws request)?

Comment: Yes it will. because the data is not actually downloaded in single pass. It is being downloaded a certain byte at a time. So, untill the data is completely downloaded it will not fire the `end` event.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the `promise` function.

Comment: Thanks. It perfectly works as I intended. Except that data variable must be outside of getData function